# /index.php/rest/V1/modules File not found after upgrading to magento 2.4.2

Tags: rest-api, htaccess, magento2.4.2, not-found

after upgrading to 2.4.2 there is a problem with rest api

the url `/index.php/rest/V1/modules` responds with "File not found"
the url `/rest/V1/modules` works well

https://magento-560832-1812590.cloudwaysapps.com/index.php/rest/V1/modules

https://magento-560832-1812590.cloudwaysapps.com/rest/V1/modules

any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to phpmyadmin and run this query

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%rewrite%'
```

Change 'web/seo/use_rewrites' value to 1 if you want to exclude the index.php from the links. If you want to show index.php then change its value to 0.

Worked for me.

Comment: Refresh the cache after this process

Answer (score 0):

solved setting the webroot to the pub/ directory

Thank you